# How to toggle up menu when another menu item is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, menu, genesis

I'm working on my own child theme using the Genesis Framework. With my theme, when you click a top level menu item, the sub-menu toggles open horizontally under the menu. Right now, to close it, you need to click that same menu option. If you click another menu item while the first sub-menu is still open, the new sub-menu just appears over it, creating a layer of sub-menus.

I've looked through multiple threads here and have tried using `e.stopPropagation();` as others have suggested. I'm sure I'm using it wrong as it's not working.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".nav-header-left .menu-item, .nav-header-right .menu-item").removeClass("menu-open");

    jQuery(".nav-header-left .menu-item-has-children, .nav-header-right .menu-item-has-children")
    .click( function( e ){
        jQuery(this).find( 'ul.sub-menu:first' ).slideToggle( function() {
            jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass("menu-open");
        });

        if ( e.target !== this ) {
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle showing the displaying the functionality of the menu: https://jsfiddle.net/mve1mrcp/15/ (this has been updated a few times to make it look a little better)

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: if you can replicate your menu or a part of it in jsFiddle, or provide html/css/js for a working sample, it'll help us find a suitable answer to your question.

Comment: @AhmedMusallam Here is a fiddle of the menu: https://jsfiddle.net/mve1mrcp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the JS/CSS/HTML from your fiddle with small fixes

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".nav-header-left .menu-item, .nav-header-right .menu-item").removeClass("menu-open");

  jQuery(".nav-header-left .menu-item-has-children, .nav-header-right .menu-item-has-children")
    .click(function(e) {
      var $menuItem = jQuery(this);
      console.log($menuItem)
      var $nav = $menuItem.closest('.nav-header-left, .nav-header-right'); // get the nav parent
      var shouldClose = $menuItem.hasClass('menu-open');
      var $openMenuItem = $('.menu-open').removeClass('menu-open'); // toggle all menu items to be closed
      $openMenuItem.find('ul.sub-menu:first').hide(); // hide sub-menu
      if(!shouldClose){
        $menuItem.find('ul.sub-menu:first').slideToggle(function() {
          jQuery(this).parent().addClass("menu-open");
        });
      }
    });
    
   jQuery(document).click(function(){
    $('.menu-open').removeClass('menu-open');
   })
});
```

```css
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav {
  display: block;
}

.nav-header-left {
  background: #000;
}

.nav-header-left .genesis-nav-menu {
  text-align: left;
}

.genesis-nav-menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 22px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.nav-header-left .genesis-nav-menu li > .sub-menu {
  display: none;
  top: 104px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu {
  left: -9999px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.nav-header-left .genesis-nav-menu li > .sub-menu {
  display: none;
  top: 104px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.nav-header-left .genesis-nav-menu > .menu-item-has-children:before {
  content: "\f347";
  float: right;
  font: normal 12px/1 'dashicons';
  height: 16px;
  padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-align: right;
  z-index: 9999;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-header-left .genesis-nav-menu .menu-open .sub-menu {
  border: none;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -moz-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.nav-header-left .genesis-nav-menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.nav-header-left .genesis-nav-menu li > .sub-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.site-header .genesis-nav-menu li li {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.nav-header-left .genesis-nav-menu li > .sub-menu li a {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}

.nav-header-left .genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu a {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav-header-left">
  <ul id="menu-left" class="menu genesis-nav-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-377" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-377"><a href="#" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Courses</span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-376" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-376"><a href="#" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Ontario</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-388" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-388"><a href="#" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Nova Scotia</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-374" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-374"><a href="#" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Driving Ranges</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-375" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-375"><a href="#" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Daily Updates</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-392" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-392"><a href="#" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Loch March</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-219" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-219"><a target="_blank" href="#" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Tee Times</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-63" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-63"><a href="#" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Memberships</span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-487" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-487"><a href="#" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Member Guest Days</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-395" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-395"><a href="#" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">2018 Memberships</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-396" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-396"><a href="#" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Add-On Programs</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-398" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-398"><a href="#" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Corporate Programs</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-397" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-397"><a href="#" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">FAQs</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Musasllam This is great! One question, though. Is there any way to be able to close the menu if a menu item is clicked twice in a row instead of re-opening the menu? Or to close the menu when clicking somewhere else on the page. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Updated the answer